# Why was my question about Java and OrientDB downvoted?

Tags: discussion

The question that was downvoted was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687428/how-to-add-a-lined-document-to-a-linklist-with-the-java-api-in-orientdb).

This is a very specific question that doesn't relate to sql very well but a valid one. I got a quick and concise answer to it.

Please let me know why my question was downvoted, and what I can do to improve it for next time (if anything).

Comment: **Moderator Note**: If you've got an answer for the OP, please post it. Possible answers run the gamut from "You did everything right, OP" to "Here's how you avoid downvotes", to "here's why you were downvoted."  Comments are easy to leave; but without a full fleshed out answer, it just feels like sniping if you're on the receiving end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your question, I can see a few reasons why it might be downvoted.  Take these into consideration for when you're asking questions. We want you to do well here, but it does take more than just asking a question to gain reputation. You have to do it *well*.

Here's how you do that.

> How to add a lined document to a linklist with the java api in orientdb

The title starts out poorly;  there are a few misspellings and capitalization that should have happened.  Since the title is the first thing people see, it can attract downvotes without anyone ever looking closely at the question!

Here's how you improve that:

> How do I add a linked document to a linked list using the Java API for OrientDB?

Now on to your question text.  It's important that you spend time making sure your question 'looks' good. That's what people will vote on in the absence of understanding the tag.  Since it's a small tag, you need all the help you can get.

Your question text:

> I have a LINKLIST field "children" in a class. I want to do
>   programmatically what can be done with:update RID add {json here}
>
> my code:
>
> ```
> ODocument doc=new ODocument("ClassA"); ODocument parentDoc=db.load(new
> ORecordId(rid));
> ```
>
> how to make parentDoc field children add the new document without using SQL?

You're (again) missing capitalization and making code look like code and reserved keywords look like reserved keywords (or terms).

To improve your question:

> I have an `OType.LINKLIST` field `children` in a class.
>
> I want to use the following format to update it:
>
> ```
> update RID add {json here}
> ```
>
> I don't know how to do this without using SQL, which is my goal.
>
> #### code
>
> ```
> ODocument doc=new ODocument("ClassA");
> ODocument parentDoc=db.load(new ORecordId(rid));
> ```
>
> How do I make the `parentDoc` field `children` add the new document
>   without using SQL?

Even with all this (this helps, a lot) it's still a little unclear what's going on.  Since I lack any technical knowledge about Orient-DB, I can't help you further, but I do know that if you take the time to format your question properly, you're less likely to get downvotes, even if the question isn't the best phrased.

Comment: As I point out in my answer, it's not information so much as it is displaying the information you already have well.  As I point out, from an outsider's perspective, it's still a little unclear how all the pieces fit together (especially the `update RID` line), but my edits would get you much farther.  If you take care to format your question well, it can be the difference between downvotes and upvotes. Yes, we expect this out of people who use our site. Yes, we downvote people who don't take care in asking their questions. Conversely, we upvote those who do.

Comment: thanks that is helpful. Formatting is an issue and i will try to do it more but sometimes programmers are under stress at work. It is not enough to attract 6 downvotes so apparently something else is going on here. I have had other meta-discussions in programmers stack exchange about why I think the whole system should change a bit because people get "high" downvoting.
By the way, "update #13:0" is the real command but why put an arbitrary number rather than explaining what it is? (RID in OrientDB terms).

Comment: @arisalexis Imagine Stack Overflow as that person you see once a year, rather than that best friend that you joke around with.  You're much more likely to put your best face forward when you see someone once a year; and you certainly wouldn't show up half-dressed to meet them.  Regular forums are your 'best friend', where anything goes. Stack Overflow isn't that; we strive to be more.  That means doing our best (through upvotes and downvotes) to figure out who wants to contribute positively and who doesn't care.  If you show that you care, you'll get upvotes. If you show you don't, you won't.

Comment: @arisalexis That sounds like something that would have been great to add to the question;  people are more likely to upvote you if you explain unclear terms.

Comment: but that's exactly what was the title of my meta post. people that haven't used OrientDB will not know what RID is and they will never answer or be looking for this and people who have, they need no explanation. That's why I said we need to make people stop downvoting with closed eyes. I get it about formatting though.

Comment: *"sometimes programmers are under stress at work"* - this isn't a helpdesk. If you need immediate answers, this isn't the best place to turn. And bear in mind that others on SO have pressures too, and are all volunteers; don't make them trawl through a badly-formatted question, **make it easy for them to read and answer**. Then everyone's happy!

Comment: you know the most funny @GeorgeStocker thing is that even after you edited the question and it seems super nice , it gets downvoted :)

Comment: @arisalexis That's the meta effect for you.  In some ways it has to do with how you originally approached the question on meta; in other ways it has to do with some people react negatively when you ask why your question was downvoted. Overall though, it received 2 more upvotes than it would have otherwise. I'd consider that a win, given the hole it started out in.

Comment: unfortunately my goal was not to make my question upvoted since I received an answer and I don't really care about reputation points but to raise some issues. I think I dag a whole in the water. but seriously thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 10):

Your question shows a pattern I've seen evolving in the past year at SO.  Users have learned that posting a snippet is important to draw an answer.  Important because these days many questions don't get an answer at all.

Problem is, your snippet does absolutely nothing to document your question.  What it *looks* like is that you've made no effort at all to try this by yourself and prefer for somebody else to do your work.  Not the kind of impression you ever want to create at SO.

If you have a *possibly* valid stab at solving it yourself but the code just doesn't do what you hope it would do then *do* post that code.  Users can post a much better answer that identifies the thought problem and their answer is likely not to solve just this one problem but the next ten as well.  But if you have absolutely no idea how to even get started at it then *don't*.

Comment: what if your and others impression is wrong and there is no documentation or reference of this on the net? just a possibility I am throwing in.

Comment: Maybe it is, doesn't matter, I'm just telling you what it looks like.  I still don't know.

Answer (score 5):

> Can the mods please stop downvoting when they don't understand the subject?

What made you think mod's downvoted your question? It's random and anonymous. Anybody with a reputation more than 125 (theoritically) can downvote. And believe me, mods really have some other important work to do rather than downvoting questions (*nothing personal*). A mod, *as a mod* is least involved in judging technical accuracy of a question or answer.

You can ask for a comment in the comment, although.

Suggestion: Let's take a challenge, shall we Mr. arisalexis?

> *Edit and improve the question in a way that you get upvotes twice the number of downvotes.*

Comment: Though asking for a reason why something was down-voted is likely to get the comment deleted. Someone who down-votes isn't likely to come back and see the comment.

Comment: sourav look at my last comment and you will realize what's happening with the site.

Comment: @arisalexis Please, I request you, don't take this personally. After a while, take your time to read  [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what are usually expected from questions.

Comment: my question is super valid and i would have asked in the orientdb forums as i usually do but i just thought i can do it here. all this hatred is funny.

Comment: @arisalexis It is not about _validity_, sometimes _representation_ also have some importance, right? Just think it in the way, "what is _clear_ to you maybe _unclear_ to someone else". So, Just try to make it appear clear to everybody, hm?